# how to combine ImageView to ListView

Tags: android

i connect my database to ListView like this:

```
public void update_list(String NN) {
       c = db.rawQuery(NN, null);
       startManagingCursor(c);
       String[] from = new String[]{"_id","Fname","Lname","Phone","Car","CarNum" };
       int[] to = new int[]{  R.id._id,R.id.Fname,R.id.Lname,R.id.Phone,R.id.Car,R.id.CarNum };
       SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter (this, R.layout.my_list, c, from, to);
       setListAdapter(notes);
       setListAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.my_list, c, from,to) {

       @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        }
    });
    }
```

now i need to connect ImageView to picture

i have field PicNum that hold link to picture

i know to load picture to ImageView like this:

```
 MyPic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.MyPic);
        try
        {
        File imgFile = new File("/sdcard/MyPic/Unzip/" +MyParam.zPicNum+ ".jpeg");
        if(imgFile.exists()){
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
             MyPic.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
            }
        else
        {
             MyPic.setImageBitmap(null);
        }
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
           MyPic.setImageBitmap(null);
    }
```

how to combine this ImageView to my ListView ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this to insert image to your list view:

```
MySimpleAdapter notes;

    public class MySimpleAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

            public MySimpleAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
                super(context, layout, c, from, to);
            }

            @Override
            public void setViewImage(ImageView v, String zPicNum) {
                try{
                    String pathName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "MyPic/Unzip/" +zPicNum+ ".jpeg";
                    File path = new File(pathName);
                    if(path.exists()){
                        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName, options);
                        v.setImageBitmap(bm);
                    }
                    else{
                        v.setImageResource(R.drawable.defaultpic);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "error in finding images", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: thanks for the help, i try this but i cant see any of my picture. can i get more help ?

Answer (score 2):

Add the `PicNum` field and `R.id.MyPic` (it should be part of `R.layout.my_list`) in your `from` & `to` arrays:

```
   String[] from = new String[]{"_id","Fname","Lname","Phone","Car","CarNum","PicNum" };
   int[] to = new int[]{R.id._id,R.id.Fname,R.id.Lname,R.id.Phone,R.id.Car,R.id.CarNum, R.id.MyPic};
```

Then use the `getView()` method to fill the picture of `R.id.MyPic` before returning it:

```
@Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  if(convertView.getId()==R.id.MyPic){
    /*Your code to load the Picture to convertView*/
    return convertView;
    }else return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
   }
 });
```

Another option is to use a `ViewBinder` and check if the `View` being bound is `R.id.MyPic`, then again load the picture to it.

Comment: thank for the help, i try this but cant see any of my picture and the program crushed

Answer (score 2):

`SimpleCursorAdapter` was deprecated for a reason. And the reason is, that it will freeze your entire application until it downloads all of the images visible in the current viewport.

Answer (score 1):

What's in PicNum? If it's a URL to an image, you have to download the file and decode it before you display it, so you can't use SimpleCursorAdapter by itself. You could, if you want, subclass SimpleCursorAdapter and also extend it with the SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder interface. That would allow you to have the default bindView behavior for most columns, but then download and decode the image for PicNum.

Answer (score 1):

SimpleCursor Adapter is very easy to implement, Here is the one, which will help you to learn simple cursor adapter [Click Here](http://xebee.xebia.in/2010/12/28/android-listview-with-images-cursor/)